# Simple magento category question

Tags: php, magento

How can I stop `getChildren()` being recursive?

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2)->getChildren();
```

I only want to know the immediate children of a category, not it's grandchildren.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **addLevelFilter** :-

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addIsActiveFilter()
                    ->addLevelFilter(1)
                    ->addOrderField('name');
```

For more:- [Get list of all categories](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-list-of-all-categories/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This runs *very* slowly and gave a fatal allowed memory error. I have about 100 categories. Could this be because I have all off the caches disabled? Thanks

Comment: Are you fetching all categories or a single category? You can use addIdFilter($categoryIds) if you are fetching single or few categories.